# Google-maps - Is there a way to make directions work on walking areas?

Tags: google-maps, geo, directions

I have embedded `Google-maps` in my website, it's for a specific place. when I used directions it forces the user to go on the road. [See Examples Below].

[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell from your picture.  Is the "Google-map" Route on a road or a sidewalk?  Are you using WALKING directions?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, tell me what is your problem ?

Comment: @geocodezip, Google-map route on a road, but i need the route to work on walking areas, but this never works in google-maps even if i choose the `walking` mode. so I'm looking for alternative solution, like drawing a custom line between 2 markers.

Comment: "I'm looking for alternative solution, like drawing a custom line between 2 markers." - That should work.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I didn't try to draw a custom line between 2 markers, but you know it's not the best way to do it because you can't detect obstacles "Buildings" for example. but I have no other options if google-maps doesn't support routing on walking areas, like "Grass, Pavements, etc..", not necessarily to be a walking path.

Comment: I don't think it can be achieved. The accuracy of GPS is not that high also.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot already shows Walking directions from Google Maps.

The "Desired route" may or may not be feasible in real world, but as far as Google Maps is concerned, it's not a viable option, that's way you get the route you get. This is because there are no pedestrian path directly between those buildings.

Here is another example, in Sydney University campus: even if there is a pedestrian path directly between these buildings (and I suspect there is) Google Maps doesn't have all pedestrian paths in the world.

https://www.google.ch/maps/dir/Bosch+cafe,+Cadigal+Lane,+Camperdown,+New+South+Wales,+Australia/Bosch+Building+1B,+Cadigal+Ln,+Camperdown+NSW+2050,+Australia/@-33.8895916,151.1846882,133m/am=t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x6b12b02c944196eb:0xf6270a8aadce3489!2m2!1d151.18521!2d-33.8892892!1m5!1m1!1s0x6b12b02cf22b9c79:0x6f60bf70f2959cd7!2m2!1d151.1845779!2d-33.889655?hl=en

You will get the same route from the Directions API with `mode=walking` which already takes advantage of indoor paths, so that it will route *through* buildings if appropriate.